# How do I make Discord.py bot remove roles sooner?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots

I have made a bot which automates role adding and removal. It all works, but the adding works in 15/20 seconds after running the command. The removal takes up to 15 minutes.

What am I doing wrong? I have started a few months ago with programming and started with Python, so any hint is usefull.

The guildid, channelid and roleid are numbers now, I put placeholders in.

```py
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def autoderolergame():
        tasks = []
        guild = client.get_guild(guildid)
        channel = guild.get_channel(channelid)
        role = guild.get_role(roleid)
        for member in guild.members:
            if member not in channel.members:
                try:
                    await member.remove_roles(role, reason='Leaving Voice channel')
                except:
                    pass
            if str(member.status) == 'offline':
                try:
                    await member.remove_roles(role, reason='Going offline, so no more VIP rain')
                except:
                    pass
```

I also try to subtitute 'for member in guild.members' with
'async for member in guild.fetch_members():'
Sadly this made no difference.

I am thinking about saving a list of users in the channel and updating that every 10 seconds and then look at the list and select all users which aren't in the channel anymore, remove the role and then remove them from the list, would that be a better solution?
I rather don't because I would like to use the built in functions of Discord.py.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem.
I was using the code to look at all the guild members.

Since I want roles to be removed upon leaving the channel, I only needed too look at the roles a user has and then check if they are still in the room.

So this is my new code:

```
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def autoderolergame():
        tasks = []
        guild = client.get_guild(guildid)
        channel = guild.get_channel(channelid)
        role = guild.get_role(roleid)
        for member in role.members: (<-- only changed this from guild to role)
            if member not in channel.members:
                try:
                    await member.remove_roles(role, reason='Leaving Voice channel')
                except:
                    pass
            if str(member.status) == 'offline':
                try:
                    await member.remove_roles(role, reason='Going offline, so no more VIP rain')
                except:
                    pass
```

I also changed to seconds to a longer interval because of the tip Łukasz Kwieciński gave me regarding the rate limit. It's not an issue now since it works like 1000x times faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an asynchronous approach to make it faster

```py
import asyncio

remove_roles_semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(20)

async def remove_role(member, role, reason):
    async with remove_roles_semaphore:
        try:
            await member.remove_roles(role, reason=reason)
        except:
            pass


@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def autoderolergame():
    guild = client.get_guild(guildid)
    channel = guild.get_channel(channelid)
    role = guild.get_role(roleid)

    tasks = []

    for member in guild.members:
        if member not in channel.members:
            tasks.append(remove_role(member, role, 'Leaving Voice channel')
        if str(member.status) == 'offline':
            tasks.append(remove_role(member, role, 'Going offline, so no more VIP rain')

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

Though keep in mind that you can get easily ratelimited for this, if you hit the global ratelimit (50 requests per second) you can get banned. Use this method at your own risk (you might want to enable [`logging`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/logging.html) to see any ratelimit warnings)

I used `asyncio.Semaphore` to limit the amount of requests made concurrently, feel free to change the value, but remember -- the higher the value the higher the chances to get banned (**do not exceed 50**).

*Sadly I cannot really test the code so I can't promise that it's going to be faster.*

Comment: Tried that too, but without semaphore that didn't make a difference sadly. Thought that would work honestly. But I might try this with the semaphore option, this might make the difference. Thanks for answering my question. I will try and report back in a day or two to let you know if it worked!

Comment: If it didn't work without a semaphore, it's going to be even slower if you add it. I only used it to limit the amount of coroutines that run concurrently at the same time. If this doesn't work I honestly think that there isn't an answer here sadly

Comment: I was afraid so, the Discord service doesn't like it that much. Thanks for looking at it and try to help me out.